# Why is #include breaking global variables?

Tags: include, global-variables, autohotkey

I have a simple `.ahk` file which reloads the currently running script any time I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
; reload-hotkey.ahk

Esc::Reload     ; reload script with Esc
```

**For some reason, importing this file causes global variables to stop working properly.**

```
; test-file.ahk

#Include %A_ScriptDir%\reload-hotkey.ahk    ; This line causes the problem
globalString := "Hello"
^q::
   localString := "World"
   MsgBox '%globalString% %localString'     ; Output: ' World'
Return
```

If I remove my `#include` statement, the code works as expected.

```
; test-file-2.ahk

globalString := "Hello"
^q::
   localString := "World"
   MsgBox '%globalString% %localString%'    ; Output: 'Hello World'
Return
```

This only happens if my included file includes a hotkey. If the function only includes methods or functions, my code will work as expected.

For reference, I am using AutoHotkey Unicode 32-bit 1.1.26.01.

**Why would an `#include` statement cause global variables to not work properly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable definitions must occur before any hotkey or hotstring definitions.

So put the variable definition above the include statement.

```
globalString := "Hello"
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\reload-hotkey.ahk    ; This line causes the problem
```

For more information, see the [Auto-execute Section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) in the Autohotkey documentation.

Comment: I would add that statements like [CoordMode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm) and [SetKeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) also need to be placed after any hotkey or hotstring definitions.